# How to recursively compare vectors?

Tags: c++, loops, recursion

I'm trying to write a function which recursively checks if a given vector A is in any contiguous block in vector B. For example, if `A={5,6,7}` and `B={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}`, it should return true. If `B = {1,2,3,4,5,7,6}`, it should return `false`. Currently, my code keeps outputting `true` because I don't think my logic is correct. I have not been able to modify it to produce any results yet. Any help will be appreciated!

```
bool r_app(vector<int>& a1, vector<int> b1, size_t k)
{
    k=0;

    if (a1.size() == 0) {
        cout << "true";
        return true;;
    }

    for (int i=0;i<a1.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<b1.size();j++){  
            if (a1.at(i)==b1.at(j)) {
                cout << "true" << endl;
                return true;
            }   
        }
        cout << "false" << endl;
        return false;    

        return r_app(a1,b1,k+1);   
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** So this is what I got from Smac89, and I added the cout lines so that when I call the function in main, it outputs either true or false. The function currently outputs true for every true input, but doesnt output false.. I'm not sure why.

```
bool r_app(std::vector<int>& a1, std::vector<int> &b1, std::size_t start)
{
    std::size_t savedPos = start + 1, k = 0;

    for (; k < a1.size() && start < b1.size() && a1[k] == b1[start]; 
         k++, start++)
    {
            if (k != 0 && a1[0] == b1[start])
                savedPos = start;
    }
    if (k == a1.size())
        cout << "true" << endl;
        return true;
    if (start < b1.size())
        return r_app(a1, b1, savedPos);

    cout << "false" << endl;  
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `a1.at(i)=b1.at(j)` is not an equality test, you are assigning the values in one vector to the values in the other. You forgot one equals sign. (`=` is assignment; `==` is equality testing.) Further, even with an actual equality test, this will stop on the first equal element and declare the test complete -- it will return true if the first vector contains any element that is equal to any element in the second vector.

Comment: @cdhowie That totally slipped my mind, thanks. However, I'm still not sure how i would modify my loop so that it checks if all elements in A are present in B.

Comment: try to use `std::search`.  `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: Assuming you want to roll your own, if you think about it, what you really want to do in your outer loop is to just find occurrences of `b1.at(0)` in `a1`.  Any matching substring of `b1` in `a1` must implicitly start with `b1.at(0)`.  Once you have a match, remember the starting position, and then iterate along `b1` checking successive characters from `a1` with the corresponding character in `b1`.  Return `true` only if you reach the end of `b1` with all characters matching.

Comment: @dgnuff But iterating in a loop isn't recursion. ;)

Comment: The poster's original answer isn't strictly recursive, since I don't see any instances of a routine calling itself.  Any solution to a substring search will generally wind up as a pair of nested `for` loops, the trick is doing the correct work set in each loop.  Most notably, doing a precheck for `a1.at(i) == b1.at(0)` saves you the bother of even starting the inner loop when you can easily detect that it'll terminate on the first iteration.  Also, I'm very well aware of the quote "To iterate is human, to recurse is divine".  I'm just a regular human being. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
bool r_app(std::vector<T>& a1, std::vector<T> &b1, std::size_t start) {
    std::size_t savedPos = start + 1, k = 0;

    for (; k < a1.size() && start < b1.size() && a1[k] == b1[start]; 
         k++, start++)
    {
            if (k != 0 && a1[0] == b1[start])
                savedPos = start;
    }
    if (k == a1.size())
        return true;
    if (start < b1.size())
        return r_app(a1, b1, savedPos);

    return false;
}

template <typename T>
bool r_app(std::vector<T>& a1, std::vector<T>& b1) {
    return r_app(a1, b1, 0);
}
```

Example:
http://rextester.com/COR69755

EDIT:
[V2](http://rextester.com/NXA14675)
Now more efficient searching - start a search either where the last search ended or at a character that matches the start of the search string

You can also print out where the first match occurred by looking at `savedPos - 1`

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped me a lot. Please check my edit in the post. For some reason, I am not able to print out false when the input results in false but it works for true.

Comment: You forgot braces `{}`

Comment: Also see the edit which now contains a faster version of the code

Comment: Thanks! One question, in the for loop in the beginning, there's a ';' right in the beginning, I don't understand that?

Comment: " for (; k < a1.size()..." <-- this part

Comment: Yes a for-loop is usually in the form `for(varaiable; condition; modify)`, but you are allowed to exclude any of them that you don't need, so since I didn't need to declare anything for `vairable`, I simply left it blank and that is why there is an extra `;` there

Answer (score 1):

You need<sup>1</sup> two recursive functions here if you want to do everything recursively.

One to test if the sequence is found at a particular point, and one to use this other function to test for equality at every point.  Here is a simple template implementation that will work with any STL container that allows iteration, as well as non-STL sequences (such as raw arrays):

```
template <typename NeedleIterator, typename HaystackIterator = NeedleIterator>
bool recursive_sequence_equals(
    NeedleIterator needle_begin,
    NeedleIterator needle_end,
    HaystackIterator haystack_begin,
    HaystackIterator haystack_end)
{
    // The sequences are equal because we reached the end of the needle.
    if (needle_begin == needle_end) {
        return true;
    }

    // If we reached the end of the haystack, or the current elements are not equal
    // then the sequences are not equal here.
    if (haystack_begin == haystack_end || *needle_begin != *haystack_begin) {
        return false;
    }

    // We are not at the end of the haystack nor the needle, and the elements were
    // equal.  Move on to the next element.
    return recursive_sequence_equals(
        ++needle_begin, needle_end,
        ++haystack_begin, haystack_end);
}

template <typename NeedleIterator, typename HaystackIterator = NeedleIterator>
HaystackIterator recursive_sequence_find(
    NeedleIterator needle_begin,
    NeedleIterator needle_end,
    HaystackIterator haystack_begin,
    HaystackIterator haystack_end)
{
    // We reached the end with no match.
    if (haystack_begin == haystack_end) {
        return haystack_begin;
    }

    // If the sequences are equal at this point, return the haystack iterator.
    if (recursive_sequence_equals(needle_begin, needle_end,
                                  haystack_begin, haystack_end)) {
        return haystack_begin;
    }

    // Check the next position in the haystack.
    return recursive_sequence_find(
        needle_begin, needle_end,
        ++haystack_begin, haystack_end);
}
```

Used like this:

```
std::vector<int> a = { 5, 6, 7 };
std::vector<int> b = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

auto found = recursive_sequence_find(
    a.begin(), a.end(),
    b.begin(), b.end());

if (found != b.end()) {
    // There was a match, found is an iterator to the beginning of the match in b.
} else {
    // No match.  (Or both containers were empty!)
}
```

([Demo](http://ideone.com/5cF7M8))

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically you can do this with one function if you use some extra parameters to convey whether or not you are in the middle of an equality test.  However this adds a lot of extra complication to the logic for no gain.  It's easier and more straightforward to implement using two different recursive functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool r_app(vector<int> a, vector<int> b, int starta, int startb)
{
    if(a.size() == 0) return 0;
    if(starta == 0) {
        int i=0;
        while(1) {
            while(a[0] != b[i] && i < b.size())
                i++;
            if(i >= b.size()) return 0;
            if(r_app(a, b, starta+1, i+1) == 1)
                return 1;
            else i++;
        }
    }
    else {
        if(starta == a.size())
            return 1;
        else if(startb == b.size())
            return 0;
        else if(a[starta] == b[startb])
            return r_app(a, b, starta+1, startb+1);
        else
            return 0;
    }   
}
int main() {
    vector<int> a;
    vector<int> b;
    b.push_back(1);
    b.push_back(2);
    b.push_back(3);
    b.push_back(4);
    b.push_back(5);
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(4);
    cout << r_app(a,b,0,0);
    return 0;
}
```

It will be easier if you do not use recursion. Also, KMP algorithm will give you much optimized solution.

Answer (score 0):

My try, using `iterator`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename Iter>
bool r_app(Iter first_a, Iter last_a, Iter first_b, Iter last_b)
{
    if(first_a == last_a)   //trivial case
        return true;

    auto found = std::find(first_b, last_b, *first_a);
    if(found == last_b)
        return false;
    else
        return r_app(++first_a, last_a, found, last_b);   //recursion
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a{5,6,7};
    std::vector<int> b{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    std::cout << r_app(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),b.end());

    return 0;
}
```