# String within a string recursive function error

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a problem with a recursive function I'm trying to write. The purpose of the function is to find a string within a string and then return the index at which the second string is located inside the first using recursion.

I am able to do this. The problem comes when the second string isn't contained in the first string. I'm want to out to the user that the second string was not found. I can't get it to relay that message.

```
int index_of(string s, string t){
  int len1 = s.length(), len2 = t.length(), index = 0;
  if (len1==len2){
     if (s.substr(index, len2) == t){
       return index;
     }else{
       return -1;
     }
  else{
    index++;
    return index_of(s.substr(index, len1),t)+index;
  }
}

int main(){ 
  string strOne = "", strTwo = "";
  cout << "This program will find the ocurrence of one string within        another.\n\nEnter the string to be searched:\t";
  getline(cin, strOne);
  cout << "\nNow enter the string you want to search for:\t";
  getline(cin, strTwo);
  int index = index_of(strOne, strTwo);
  if (index == -1){
    cout << "\nThe second string cannot be found. Sorry!\n\n";}
  else{
    cout << "\nThe index of the substring is:\t" << index << "\n\n";
  }
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You shouldn't use recursive function for that purpose. On large strings you get stack overflow.

Comment: I am not a c++ programmer, but can you compare strings like this: 'str1 == str2'? Don't you have to use strcmp(str1, str2)? I think the first option only compares the addresses of the strings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recursively compare vectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353067/how-to-recursively-compare-vectors)

Comment: What do you want the function to do if `s` does not contain `t`? Write a message to `stdout`? Throw an exception? Return -1?

Comment: 2 problems. 1) the -1 is going to be increased by the caller. 2) the length comparison should be `>=` not `==`

Answer (score 0):

If first string doesn't contain the second, `index` being incremented infinitely making `string s` zero length. So you have to check, whether the first string is shorter than the second. If so, it doesn't contain the substring.

```
  if (len1 < len2){
    // first string doesn't contain the second
    return -2;
  }else if (len1==len2){
    ...
```

But you shouldn't use recursive function here at all. Also there is a built-in function `find` in `string`:
Check this question: [Check if a string contains a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340281/check-if-a-string-contains-a-string-in-c)

Comment: `std::find` looks for a single character.  For searching for a substring, you need `std::search`.

Comment: Not exactly, there are several overloads: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: But that's not what you said.  The only interpretation I can put on "built-in function" is "standard library function", not "member function".

Comment: Yeah, by "built-in function" I ment that this function already exists in `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems in the code you've posted, first
and formost, that it won't compile, because you don't define
`index` in `index_of`.  And of course, you only do the
comparison whenthe two strings are the same length.  But it's
hard to figure out what the comparison is that you're trying to
do, since you take a substring based on the undefined variable
`index`; if `index` is `0`, the there is no point in taking the
substring, and if `index` isn't `0`, then
`s.substr( index, len2 ) == t` can never be true (since you only
enter this branch if both `s` and `t` have the same length.

What you really have to do is start by defining in plain English what
the function should do:

- If `s` is shorter than `t`, no match is possible, so you
  return -1.
- Otherwise, if the start of `s` is equal to `t`, you return the
  current index.
- Otherwise, you recurse on the substring of `s`, removing the
  first character (and incrementing `index`).

Of course, you also need to maintain `index` somewhere; in classical
recursion, this would be as an additional function argument.

Frankly, I would *not* construct all of those substrings.  It's far more
idiomatic in C++ to use iterators.  And I would wrap the recursive
function in a non-recursive one, so that the user wouldn't have to pass
in any extra arguments: the user might call something like:

```
int
indexOf( std::string const& text, std::string const& target )
{
    return indexOf( 0, text.begin(), text.end(), target );
}
```

Or, without passing the extra argument:

```
int
indexOf( std::string const& text, std::string const& target )
{
    std::string::const_iterator results 
            = search( text.begin(), text.end(), target );
    return results == text.end()
        ?  -1
        :  results - text.begin();
}
```

(I'm assuming that this is homework; one wouldn't normally use recursion
for a problem like this.  Otherwise, of course, just call `std::search`
in the second version, and the job is done.  Or `text.find( target )`,
which returns almost exactly what you want.)